# Publish an Open Graph Story from url / hyperlink

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have successfully created a story in my Facebook App's Open Graph module.

The story is:

"John [picked] [Brasil] as new world champions in MYDOMAIN'S World Cup of Football Pool"

[pick] is the action, [country] is the country the user chooses. This seems to work fine. But the next step has got me puzzled.

I want visitors that are logged in via Facebook on on my website to click the flag of the country that they think will win the upcoming world cup. Subsequently, the above story is published to their timeline.

I have no idea how to set this up.  The dev center of Facebook is extensive, but not very clear when it comes to this step of the process for a PHP newbe like myself.

I *assume* that the hyperlinks that the flags on my page would represent, need to look something like this:

http://mydomain.com/storypublisher.php?&country="Brazil"&image="Brazilflag.jpg" etc.

So my questions are:

- what is the correct code for storypublisher.php?
- What would be the proper format for the url I mentioned above?

I have read the various tutorials on 'Recipe' etc. but they have me puzzled when it comes to the part where you actually start publishing the above story.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Adopt it to your needs for the code part. Use the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk).

```
// 0. We don't need to clear session
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '',
    'secret' => '',
));

$fbCurrentUserID = $facebook->getUser();

// 1. If we cant get the user log him in and request permissions This requests combined permissions (basic + post)
if (!$fbCurrentUserID){
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'publish_actions',            
        'redirect_uri' => $current_url, // Replace here
    ));
    $this->abortToUrl($loginUrl);
}

// 2. So we do have a current FB user. Lets try to read data (Maybe he declined perms)
try {
    // 2.a Check if has granted us the perms and post
    $isGranted = $facebook->api(array(
        "method"    => "users.hasAppPermission",
        "ext_perm"  => "publish_actions",
        "uid"       => $fbCurrentUserID,
    ));

    if (!$isGranted){
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'publish_actions',
            'redirect_uri' => $current_url // Replace here
        ));
        die(header('Location: '. $login_url .''));
    }


    $res = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(
        'link' => '', // Replace and fill with your params
        'name' => '', // Replace and fill with your params
        'message' => '', // Replace and fill with your params
        'description' => '', // Replace and fill with your params
        'picture' => '', // Replace and fill with your params
    ));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    // 2.b Log any error and retry please

    die(header('Location: /'));
}
```

As far for the rest use a small form to post to the facebook controller. Prefer $_POST from $_GET if you pass a lot of data. Then from the controller get them and fill the `replace here` comments I left in the code. You will need further guidance if you are PHP newbie. Starting with facebook SDK controller is the wrong start in my humble opinion. Well I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I understand your example up to the part where you call the api via POST and I have to define 'link' 'name' 'message' etc. I was under the impression that an Open Graph story requires actions to be formatted like this: https://graph.facebook.com/me/objects/MYAPPNAME:country?
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&
method=POST&
object=

Assuming my action is called 'PICK' and the Object is called 'COUNTRY', how do I define that in the url values the user submits via GET (or POST as you suggested)

Comment: @user3097481 if you are using the php SDK then not. as you can see you are contructing a facebook object that uses that. Small advise: The facebook docs are outdated. Look here for the SDK and ho to use it! 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: @user3097481 The code that I posted is based on the Facebook SDK. The benefit of that is that you don't need to construct your params and queries for most of the cases. Check the link above and things will get clear I hope. Facebook developers will be updating their docs soon as they replied on some issues in github

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, I'll have a look and see where it gets me!

Comment: @user3097481 Good luck :-) . It's a hard road ahead